# PreSignUp failed with SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module in Cognito PreSignup Lambda

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to create a new user with a Cognito PreSignup Lambda trigger, but I am getting the error `PreSignUp failed with error SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

In the CloudWatch logs I see the following error message:

```
2022-12-25T21:39:04.238Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {
    "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
    "errorMessage": "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module",
        "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:222:13)",
        "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:300:17)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:34)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)",
        "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)",
        "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
    ]
}
```

I have tried adding `'type': 'module'` in the package.json file, but that caused several additional errors such as `'Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App' in …/'api/src' Did you mean 'App.js'?`.

Below is my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import config from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(config);


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

How can I fix this error and successfully create a new user with my Cognito PreSignup Lambda trigger?

Comment: Is your lambda nodejs version 14?

Comment: I'm running node v18.4.0 but I just noticed the lambda run times are Node.js 14.x. Would that be the issue?